# Concatenate string in HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, velocity

I'm using Apache Velocity and need to append a string to a variable that I'm accessing using velocity.

---

Here's my current code with the desired functionality.

```
<div id="$settings.name" + "Setting"></div>
```

`$settings.name` is a variable being parsed by Velocity and `"Setting"` is the literal I want to append to it.

---

Can anyone provide me some information on how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A cursory google search has revealed the answer:

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#string-concatenation

It looks like you'll need to write it like this:

```
id="${settings.name}Setting"
```

Comment: Thankyou! I have been reading through their documentation for everything else but I thought this would be something HTML sided that I had to do.